# python map iterate over a list and function on another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, mapreduce

How in Python is the map function used to iterate over a list (iterable) and do the logic on another list(iterable). For example, we have a list of indices as `indices` and a list of strings as `str_list`. Then, we want to make the the element at index `i` taken from `indices` of `str_list` to be empty. Yes, the indices are guaranteed to be in the range of `str_list` length. There are simple ways to do, however, I want to figure out how the map function does work on two separate list scenarios. This I came up with has error:

```
  str_list = map(lambda index : str_list[index] = "", indices)

  SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this. `map()` is intended to *map* a collection to another collection. Using it for side-effects is a pretty strong code smell.

Comment: I am just curios how will it be done. what does this mean: "Using it for side-effects"?

Comment: You should probably just us a `for` loop. The problem is that `str_list[index] = ""` is not an expression, it does not produce a value. With `map` each iteration should produce a value that ends up as one item in outputs of map. For example `map(lambda i: i*10, range(5))` maps the values `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` -> `0, 10, 20, 30, 40`. With the assignment of `str_list = map(...)` the new value of `str_list` won't be anything meaningful because you map function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Side-effect means it is changing something outside the local environment rather than being a pure function which takes some input and produces an output. In this example the side-effect you are hoping for is the mutation of `str_list`.

Comment: this doesn't have error: ```def try(i, str_list):
            str_list[i] = ""
        map(try(i, str_list), indices)``` but the logic doesn't work as expected, but this one still has error: ```map(lambda i, str_list : str_list[i] = "", indices)```. Why that and why the logic doesn't work as I want it to do ```for ind in indices:
        s_list[ind] = ""```

Comment: `map()` takes each value in an iterator like a list and calls your function on it. The end value will be the return value of each of those functions. So you need to ask, what it the return value of your function `try()`?

Comment: you cannot use assignment statements in lambda expressions, because they can only contain other expressions, not statements. A lambda expression, `lambda <args>: <expression>` is equivalent to `def func(<args>): return <expression>`, so think about it, `return str_list[index] = ""` doesn't work. But **also** I want to re-iterate, you **shouldn't use `map` / list comprehensions for side-effects**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Lambda function can only contain a single expression. Assignment with the `=` operator is a statement, so it doesn't work in your example.

You can do the assignment with `list.__setitem__`, however:

```py
>>> strings = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']
>>> indices = [1, 3]
>>> list(map(lambda x: strings.__setitem__(x, ''), indices))
[None, None]
>>> list(strings)
['zero', '', 'two', '']
```

This is an abuse of `map`, so I would advise against doing it for real.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why is it abuse of map. My query was mainly to use logic on another iterable while we iterate on another iterable. Is this itself abuse of map or just if this is for string?

Comment: The reason it is an abuse is you have made code that produces the value `[None, None]`. Did you need to make this new list? The effect of changing `strings` is a *side effect*. In larger programs side-effects are often unexpected and hard to debug, which leads to functional paradigms like `map()` which produce new values rather than mutating state.

Comment: The comments to the original question got at it: using `map` with a function that has side effects (rather than just returning a value) would raise my eyebrows in a code review. "Please use a loop, to save the poor next person who has to look at this several moments of puzzlement" is what I would say.

Also, you can see that it's wasteful - `map` doesn't iterate; the `list()` call around it does. So we produce this useless `[None, None]` output.

Comment: Thank you both! for sure in practice this is overkill, hard to debug and I never use this. I mostly wanted to see how to use map using two different iterables one as source and the other as destination of the logic. In Java these can be done with less side effects and cleaner, i think, which has more built-in functionalities to play with streams.

Comment: @Alan I think you are confused. This has nothing to do with *capabilities* of `map` vs Java streams. You can wirte a function and do this assignment and use `map` to do it. The point is **you shouldn't**. Neither in Java nor in Python. These are functional constructs and should be used with pure functions, not for side effects